# Redux mapStateToProps does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

When a component changes through a Redux action, the `ques` appear to be entered and the reminder has changed. However, if imported into `mapStateToProps` from another component, the value does not change and only the empty value is entered. Why? [This is my github](https://github.com/chosungwon/vote_app)

## components/Vote

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { INFOMATION } from "../actions";

const postInitialState ={
    id: '',
    ques: '',
    ans1: '',
    ans2: ''
};


const postInfomation = (state = postInitialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case INFOMATION:
        console.log(state)
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            id: action.id,
            ques: action.ques,
            ans1: action.ans1,
            ans2: action.ans2
        });
    default:
        return state
    }
};



const postApp = combineReducers({
    postInfomation
});

export default postApp;
```

## reducer/vote

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Vote extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h1>qwe</h1>
                <h1>{this.props.id}</h1>
                <h1>{this.props.ques}</h1>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        id: state.postInfomation.id,
        ques: state.postInfomation.ques,
        ans1: state.postInfomation.ans1,
        ans2: state.postInfomation.ans2
    };
}

Vote = connect(mapStateToProps) (Vote);

export default Vote;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the value does not change and only the empty value is entered."? Also, you have `qus` instead of `ques` in some parts of your code, which might be causing issues.

Comment: As you can see by going into github, there are no errors regarding typos. When you act on A component and the reducer changes the ques value, it does not change when you import the value through mapStateToProps in the B Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is functioning, but by visiting the `/vote` page your app reloads and the state is reinitialized. You can spot this with the [Redux Devtools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension), which shows the `@@INIT` call when navigating.

If you add a `<Link to="/vote">Vote</Link>` to navigate to the `/vote` route you'll notice the state remains. If you use the `HashRouter` you won't have this problem because the browser won't reload the page.

--

Do note that there are more issues with your state logic. Everytime a user updates one of your inputfields you update the redux store, and your local state. But when the user subsequently submits the form you only update the id of the local state, that id is only put in the redux state if the user changes one of the input fields again.

I would only update the redux state after submitting the form. Keep the values in local state until that time. Also move your axios call to a service that you call via your action with `redux-thunk`.